# Locus of a point for the given equation

Tags: geometry, locus

Equation of a line is given by $y + 2at = t( x - at^2)$, $t$ being a parameter. Find the locus of the point of intersection of the line which are at right angles?

My Approach: I found out the point of intersection
($a(\frac{t^4 + t^2 + 1}{t^2}), a(\frac{1-t^2}{t}))$.

Don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: I could not make out how have you reached there? $$\dfrac x{y+1}=?$$ $$(t+1/t)^2-(t-1/t)^2=4,$$ right?

Comment: Shouldn't $a$ appear somewhere in the expression for the intersection point?

Comment: Yes, a will appear in the intersection point.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your point of intersection

Comment: Is the answer correct or am I going somewhere wrong

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You already got point of intersection as $$ a\left(\frac{t^4+t^2+1}{t^2}\right) , a\left(\frac{1-t^2}{t}\right) $$ So $$ y^2 =a^2\left(\frac{t^4-2t^2+1}{t^2}\right)$$ $$ y^2 +3a^2 = a^2\left(\frac{t^4+t^2+1}{t^2}\right)= ax$$

Therefore $y^2+3a^2=ax$ is the required locus